# Why does \centering have no effect in my code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, horizontal-alignment

It seems that when I use the `\centering` command to center a TikZ picture within a Beamer frame, it only works if there is a blank line between the `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\end{frame}`. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw]{A Ti\emph{k}Z node, centered};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw]{Another Ti\emph{k}Z node, not centered};
\end{tikzpicture}
% Second TikZ node would be centered if there is an 
% empty line between\end{tikzpicture} and \end{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've tried surrounding the two TikZ pictures with `{}`, but it didn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: `\centering` needs a `\par` command (for example, leaving a blank line) within its scope in order to act; however, your example code produces the desired effect (both tikzpictures are centered) in my system.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks! `\par` solves the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I suggest to move your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\centering` needs an end of paragraph (for example, `\par` or leaving a blank line) within its scope in order to act; however, your example code produces the desired effect (both `tikzpicture`s are centered) in my system.